# Driver manager does not launch on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, additional-drivers

I have made a fresh install of Kubuntu 22.04, and have a following problem - I can't launch driver manager. When I go to settings, and then click on its button, xterm window opens asking for password. So then after I specify it, something gets printed in the console and afterwards it closes very quickly, so I was never able to make a screenshot in time. I am not sure how to provide more logs in this case

Edit: Seems like I got following error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this command helped:

```
sudo cp ~/.Xauthority /root
```